# How to determine in javascript when a dict of images created in django has loaded

Tags: javascript, django

I am using django and javascript. When a page is first loaded I load a dict of images (around 85 in all) and I don't want the javascript to attempt to display the images until I am sure that all of the images are loaded

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/common/load-common-data/",
            cache: false,
            success: function (context) {
                images = context.images;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    displayImages(images)
                }, 750);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This is unsatisfactory because the 750 ms delay is arbitrary and might not be sufficient in specific cases

I have seen [attempts to solve this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/571/how-to-verify-when-multiple-images-have-been-loaded-in-javascript), but they rely on loading the images individually whereas for various reasons I need to select the images in my **view** and upload them as a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a compromise. It is not ideal, but it gives the images up to 10 seconds to load (surely more than ample).

It seems a bit clunky; if anyone can suggest improvements, I'd be delighted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/common/load-common-data/",
            cache: false,
            success: function (context) {
                images = context.images;
                loadImages()
        }
    );
}

function loadImages() {
    var timeouts = [];
    var loaded = false;
    var completed = false;
    for (index = 1; index < 2000; index++) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if (Object.keys(images).length > 0) {
                loaded = true;
            }
            if (loaded && !completed) {
                displayImages(images);
                completed = true;
                for (var timeout_finished of timeouts) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout_finished)
                }
            }
        }, 10 * index);
        timeouts.push(timeout)
    }

}
```

[EDIT 1 Aug 2021. Increased the number of *timeouts* to 2000; this seems to give better performance in the production environment}